# Intermitent out of memory xamarin android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am using Visual studio on windows to debug on my android device. I already cranked up the heap to 1G and added `android:largeHeap="true"` to the manifest in the application node.

Sometime I am able to start the debugger.. IN other times it will stop to the java.lang.OOM error. If I press Debug again.. it works.

How can I make it works everytime ?

**here is the error:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       XA5213: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -Xmx1G -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\lib\dx.jar" --dex --no-strict --output obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\android\bin C:\Users\cpu\Desktop\programmation\my-project\project\obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\android\bin\classes.zip "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\mono.android.jar" obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\10\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\12\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\13\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\14\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\15\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\16\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\17\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\18\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\19\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\20\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\21\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\22\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\23\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\24\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\25\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\26\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\27\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\28\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\29\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\3\jl\okhttp-2.4.0.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\30\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\31\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\4\jl\okio-1.5.0.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\5\jl\picasso-2.5.2.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\7\jl\arch-core-common.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\8\jl\arch-lifecycle-common.jar obj\Debug\MonoAndroid90\lp\9\jl\bin\classes.jar'          0

It may be Picasso.. but I use it like this in my code so it shouldn't cause a problem with the memory I think:

```
            Picasso.With(activity)
            .Load(url)
            .Fit()
            .MemoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NoCache)
            .MemoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NoStore)
            .Into(image);
```

Comment: I would suggest you add some stacktrace and proper error message so we know what the issue is and how to help you

Comment: @G.hakim I added the log in the edited post

Comment: Weird.. it says obj/debug/monoandroid90/..../arch-core-common.jar... I installed arch-core-common once bu I deleted it from my nugget.. how could it be in the error log since it doesn't even exist in my solution. (I deleted the directory DEBUG and OBJ) restarted the build... same error.